# (QuickSight)AvgOver throwing VISUAL_CALC_REFERENCE_MISSING

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I'm new to QuickSight. I'm having trouble with the calculated fields.
My data:

| Year | Score | MeasureID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | 0.5 | ID1 |
| 2016 | 0.2 | ID2 |
| 2016 | 0.4 | ID1 |
| 2017 | 0.6 | ID1 |
| 2018 | 0.3 | ID2 |

I want to populate the avg score of each MeasureID of each year.
I used a calculated field :
avgOver(sum(Score),[MeasureID,Year]) but it I'm getting VISUAL_CALC_REFERENCE_MISSING
when Im trying to visualize. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the graph you must have the field in which you need the aggregation over. In this case [MeasureID,Year] and Score